# Why won't my Card Swipe right in this Test?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I am testing an app in `myTest()` and would like to simulate a `swipeRight` gesture on `MyCard()` composable.

When I use `performTouchInput { swipeRight() }` nothing happens. The card stays in the same place.

How can I simulate the swipe right gesture on the card? What am I missing?

### Code

```
class MyTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeRule = createComposeRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        composeRule.setContent {
                MyCard()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun myTest() = runTest {
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag("DraggableCard")
            .performTouchInput { swipeRight() }
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedTransitionTargetStateParameter")
@Composable
fun MyCard() {
    var swipeState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val transitionState = remember { MutableTransitionState(swipeState).apply { targetState = !swipeState } }
    val transition = updateTransition(transitionState, "cardTransition")

    val offsetTransition by transition.animateFloat(
        label = "cardOffsetTransition",
        transitionSpec = { tween(durationMillis = 300) },
        targetValueByState = { if (swipeState) 75f else 0f },)

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .testTag("DraggableCard")
            .offset { IntOffset(offsetTransition.roundToInt(), 0) }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectHorizontalDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                    when {
                        dragAmount >= 6 -> { swipeState = true }
                        dragAmount < -6 -> { swipeState = false }
                    }
                }
            },
        content = { Text(text = "Hello") }
    )
}
```